# ionic Image preview not available using fileuri

Tags: angular, ionic3

*Hi,
I want to preview the image which is captured . I am not able to get the preview of the image bay using fileuri, any suggestion… Below my code*

```
 capturePicture(){
const option: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
}
this.camera.getPicture(option).then((imageData) => {


this.createFileEntry(imageData);

  this.text = "Image Captured";
  this.capturing = true;
    }, (err) => {
  // Handle error
 });
}

createFileEntry(imagePath: string): Promise<any> {
console.log("imageData",imagePath)     //getting image data here

let cleansedPath = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
let d = new Date(); 
let t = d.getTime();
let newFileName: string = t + ".jpg";

return this.file.moveFile(this.file.tempDirectory+imagePath, cleansedPath, 
this.file.dataDirectory, newFileName) 
.then((entry: Entry) =>
console.log("changed",entry) 
)
.catch((err) => err.message)
 }
```

---

```
<div>
{{text}}
<ion-textarea placeholder="Enter a description" [(ngModel)]="description"> 
</ion-textarea>

<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-6 *ngIf = "!cbCheck">
    <button ion-button block icon-left color="custom" 
(click)="capturePicture()" standard>
      <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
      Camera
    </button>
  </ion-col>

  <ion-col col-6>
    <button ion-button color="custom" block [disabled]="!capturing" 
(click)='startUploading()'>Submit</button>
  </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
</ion-grid>

<img [src] = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("capturedUrl") />
</div>
```

---

*upadated the template please check once and thanks in advance*
*updated the ts file as per the suggestion but in console not getting anything can anyone check it once*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use camera FileURI, the captured photo will be saved in the application's temporary directory. The contents of the application's temporary directory is deleted when the application ends.

```
capturePicture(){
const option: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
}
this.camera.getPicture(option).then((imageData) => {
  this.capturedUrl =  imageData;
        }, (err) => {
  // Handle error
 });
}
```

Also please include this meta tag in index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ms-appdata: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

In Template:

```
<img [src] = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("capturedUrl") />
```

Component:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
```

Comment: i'm getting this line in my view  <img [src] = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("capturedUrl") />

Comment: no Actually i am not getting the image instead of that i am getting that image tag line in my view

Comment: what is the output of 'capturedUrl'?

Comment: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect..........because it violates the document's Content Security Policy. getting this issue i am not able to log in

Comment: after adding that tag in index.html head im getting the issue like refuse to connect

Comment: ok. please remove meta tag. DomSanitizer will take care for Image Cross origin issue

Comment: still not getting the image showing img tag in view

Comment: How the template content is getting displayed. using 'TemplateUrl/Template'? . Paste whole template code if possible

Comment: if i use domsanitizer then it is displaying the img tag and just now updated the whole template please check once

Comment: i got the issue. replace with this code <img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(capturedUrl)" />

Comment: sorry for the trouble again img tag gone but not displaying the image

Comment: Might be an issue with the Path where the photo is saved. please console.log capturedUrl and verify the picture exist in the location.

Comment: getting in console                  Not allowed to load local resource: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1534069241622.jpg

Comment: Device not allowing to load the local file into mobile web view. You need to get Base64 content from the File and display it. Refer this like . https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file/96252

Comment: You can use destinationType as 'DATA_URL'. Which will return Base64 content and you can display it capturedUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

Comment: this.capturedUrl =  imageData;
this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, this.capturedUrl).then(imageBase64=>{
  this.image = imageBase64;
} )
      this.text = "Image Captured";
      this.capturing = true;           not working

Comment: i know dataurl will work but i have to use file uri only

Comment: Get only the filename '1534069241622.jpg ' and assign to filename = '1534069241622.jpg '.  this.capturedUrl = imageData; this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, filename).then(imageBase64=>{ this.image = imageBase64; } ) this.text = "Image Captured"; this.capturing = true;

Comment: is there any way get only filename

Comment: You need to move the image into data directory.  createFileEntry(imagePath: string): Promise<any> {
   let cleansedPath = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
   let d = new Date();
   let t = d.getTime();
   let newFileName: string = t + ".jpg";

    return this.file.moveFile(this.file.tempDirectory, cleansedPath, this.file.dataDirectory, newFileName)
    .then((entry: Entry) => entry)
    .catch((err) => err.message)
   }

Comment: hi suresh i changed my code as per you suggestion but i'm not getting the new name of the image in my console.i updated my ts file pls check once